# select data from DB to html table and link to an other page (<a>)

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

in the table i want link a when click go to other page and select all products in this categorie
i want to put a but i dont know how to do it in the  because the td selected from the db can be multiple

```
$sql = 'SELECT categorie.id,name,username FROM categorie,user
        where user.id = categorie.added_by ';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
?>

<table class="data-table">
    <h1>Categorie List<h1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Added By</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if($result ==  false)echo "errrrr";
        else{
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                // here i want link <a> when click go to other page and 
                // select all products in this categorie
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['username'].'</td>

                </tr>';

            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in the table i want link a when click go to other page and select all products in this categorie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link should be something like this:

```
...
<td><a href="otherpage.php?categorie='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></td>
...
```

Then in otherpage.php, you can get the category ID from `$_GET['categorie']`.